# How can I make Trello lists wider?

Tags: trello

I have a wide display and lots of cards in a few columns in Trello. I’d like to make better use of my screen real estate by widening my board’s columns.

Comment: This was previously answered: see [how can i resize the column width of list in trello](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31987/how-can-i-resize-the-column-width-of-list-in-trello)

Answer (score 4):

There is the Chrome extension [FlexyTrello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flexytrello/pggiemacedhgohmpcgdpceckeicjlgfn) that allows to resize lists, or you could use [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to change the CSS of lists yourself. There is not (yet) an option to do this in the default Trello UI.

Comment: FlexyTrello does not seem to be working at the moment. When attempting to authorize with Trello: Invalid return_url. Wildcard ("*") allowed origins are no longer supported. Contact the developer. See https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/52093.